# Передать данные из дочернего окна родительскому

Tags: javascript

Родительское окно открывает дочернее для ввода набора параметров и кнопкой "Пуск".
Нажатием кнопки "Пуск" необходимо закрыть дочернее окно и вернуть введенные параметры родительскому.

Подскажите реализацию, ибо не могу понять, где переменные дочернего окна привязываются к его идентификатору, т.е. открываю дочернее как:

```
var menu=window.open("my_url","NEW",options);
```

Пытаюсь найти в потомках переменной `menu` то, что было в дочернем окне - не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы открываете из одного окна другое под именем NEW. Если из этого NEW надо передать данные в основное окно, то можно посредством запуска скрипта родительского окна, например

```
window.opener.dalee(a);
// запускает в родительском окне функцию dalee и передает ей на вход переменную - a
```

Comment: вот это оно!

Answer (score 0):

Читайте здесь - [Передача данных между формами на различных страницах, используя JavaScript](http://www.javaportal.ru/javascript/examples/loadFormFIO.html).

Comment: Не то...